# Stop the recording after some period of time

Tags: 12.04, command-line, unity, ffmpeg

I have a device that recording the video using the webcam with `ffmpeg`. It is working great,
when the recording is started I am getting the USR1 signal. And after stoping the recording we receive the USR2 signal.

But I want to stop the recording after 1 hour recording time.

I don't know but I think I have to pass the USR2 signal to the device after 1 hour.

So how can I do this...!!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use the `-t` option. From `man ffmpeg`:

> `-t` duration (input/output)
>
> When used as an input option (before `-i`), limit the *duration* of data read from the input file.
>
> When used as an output option (before an output filename), stop
>   writing the output after its duration reaches *duration*.
>
> *duration* must be a time duration specification, see the [Time duration
>   section in the ffmpeg-utils(1) manual](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Time-duration).
>
> `-to` and `-t` are mutually exclusive and `-t` has priority.

Example that records for one hour:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -t 01:00:00 output
```

Or in seconds:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -t 3600 output
```

Comment: `-t` uses the Time Duration syntax available here: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Time-duration

Answer (score 6):

If you're running ffmpeg or avconv from the command line, you could use the `timeout` command:

```
timeout 3600 avconv -f video4linux2 -r 25 -i /dev/video0  -vcodec mpeg4 -y out.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know in advance the timeout you should definetely use the methods given, however, if you really want to send a signal to the process you can use the *kill* command (despite being used 90% for TERM or KILL, can send ANY signal - kill -s USR2 pid)